# SSL issue with HttpGet probably because server is requesting client authentication

Tags: java, ssl, httpclient, ssl-certificate, http-get

We are using following versions of diff libraries

```
Apache-HttpComponents-HttpCore = 4.1;
Apache-HttpComponents-HttpClient = 4.1.1;
JDK                            = 1.6_64;
```

and suddenly started facing SSLPeerUnverifiedException ([HTTP Get failing for HTTPS with javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676205/http-get-failing-for-https-with-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception) for details).

I tried different things but I don't know why we are unable to connect to https://www.google.com even after accepting all the certificates (though as explained in the comment, it could cause man in the middle attack).

Could it be the case that Google started expecting certificate from the client? If yes, what should we do?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried to set `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl`?

Comment: No, will try for sure!

Comment: I am getting 'ssl_error_rx_record_too_long' while trying from browser with same proxy that I use with HttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

> Could it be the case that Google started expecting certificate from the client? If yes, what should we do?

If i understand you right and google truly need certificates, you should use cryptoprovider and make signatures by stunnel.

Maybe smth wrong with your code ? This settings are works for me

```
public HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
    try {
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);

        SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

        ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

        return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why allow potential MITM attacks with `ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER`?